# Can I create bootable .iso file after kernel compilation for the customized kernel in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, ubuntu-14.04, iso, iso9660

Is it possible to create ISO Image of our current running operating system of Ubuntu? And my goal is to compile new kernel and make an ISO file.

Comment: Yes, it’s possible.

Comment: Dear @0andriy, could you please guide me for creating ISO Image of my current running operating system (Ubuntu-16.04).                                      Thanks,

Comment: @0andriy, can you please provide a how-to guide.

Answer (score 4):

```
mkdir -p test/boot/grub
nano test/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

in grub.cfg:

```
menuentry "myos" {
    linux /boot/bzImage
    initrd /boot/custom-initramfs.cpio.gz
}
```

save and close.

custom-initramfs.cpio.gz: mk.sh

```
rm -r /usr/src/initramfs
mkdir -p /usr/src/initramfs/bin
mkdir -p /usr/src/initramfs/dev
mkdir -p /usr/src/initramfs/etc
mkdir -p /usr/src/initramfs/etc/network
mkdir -p /usr/src/initramfs/lib
mkdir -p /usr/src/initramfs/lib64
mkdir -p /usr/src/initramfs/mnt/root
mkdir -p /usr/src/initramfs/proc
mkdir -p /usr/src/initramfs/root
mkdir -p /usr/src/initramfs/sbin
mkdir -p /usr/src/initramfs/sys
mkdir -p /usr/src/initramfs/sys/class/net
gcc -pthread -Wall -static arp.c -o /usr/src/initramfs/init
sudo cp -a /dev/null /usr/src/initramfs/dev/
sudo cp -a /dev/console /usr/src/initramfs/dev/
sudo cp -a /dev/tty /usr/src/initramfs/dev/
sudo cp -a interfaces /usr/src/initramfs/etc/network/
sudo cp -a /sbin/ip /usr/src/initramfs/sbin/
sudo cp -a /sbin/ifconfig /usr/src/initramfs/sbin/
sudo cp -a /sbin/route /usr/src/initramfs/sbin/
sudo cp -a /sbin/dhclient /usr/src/initramfs/sbin/
sudo cp -a /sbin/dhclient-script /usr/src/initramfs/sbin/
sudo cp -a /bin/busybox /usr/src/initramfs/bin/
sudo cp -a /bin/grep /usr/src/initramfs/bin/
chmod +x /usr/src/initramfs/init
cd /usr/src/initramfs
find . -print0 | cpio --null -ov --format=newc | gzip -9 > /home/mahdi/Desktop/test/boot/custom-initramfs.cpio.gz
```

bzImage : after make linux kernel.
goto linux source downloaded
example location: /linux-stable/arch/x86/boot.
next step:

```
sudo cp -a bzImage test/boot/
grub-mkrescue -o myos.iso test
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install mtools